# How to get the "LaTeX" symbol correctly?

Tags: symbols

I am trying to write "LaTeX" in my latex file, but on writing \LaTeX, I am getting this output:

[image]

What I want is the standard way in which LaTeX is written. How do I go about getting it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: What do yo mean by *standard way*? It is the one with roman font?

Comment: Don't use the slash then, just TYPE LaTeX as standard TEXT.

Comment: @Cragfelt Yes, I meant that!

Comment: @Chen Actually that didn't help as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your current font is probably a sans-serif one (Latin Modern/Computer moder Sans Serif, I guess). You may use a macro such as

```
\newcommand{\mylatex}{\textrm{\LaTeX}}
```

to ensure that `\LaTeX` is typesetted the way you want, whatever the current font is.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\mylatex}{\textrm{\LaTeX}}
\begin{document}
\sffamily This is \LaTeX{} versus \mylatex.
\end{document}
```

[image]